# CSS Style within a style?

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a style within a style?

For example, something like this:

```
#content
{
text-align: center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color: #121212;

     h1
     {
       font-family: arial;
     }

}
```

What I am actually trying to do is have the header font as arial only inside the content div.

Comment: With: http://sass-lang.com/ you can ;)

Comment: this would be a nice feature for css

Comment: Came here, because I saw such form of CSS out there in the wild. Thx for clarification @veritas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, only like that:

```
#content
{
text-align: center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color: #121212;
}


#content h1
{
       font-family: arial;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need

```
#content
{
    text-align: center;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:10px;
    border-color: #121212;
}

#content #header
{
    font-family: arial;
}
```

**Update**: Since your question has changed

```
#content h1
{
    font-family: arial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) if you want to, but the other solutions posted here work fine too. If you include LESS, you need to have a javascript include to parse the LESS to actual CSS (from the website):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also parse the CSS server-side with node.js and serve the compiled CSS document.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
#content
{
text-align: center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color: #121212;
}

#content > #header
{
font-family: arial;
}
```

It will only set the font to arial inside the header.

This is the correct way for nesting in css

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as for many style sheets get messy easily

```
#content{text-align: center; border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color: #121212;}
h1 { font-family: arial;}
```

basically, it doesn't matter whenever you close your {}
 at the same line, or if you indent.  What is showed saves space.